# Exporting Weka DecisionTree from Java API to XML or JSON

Tags: java, xml, json, classification, weka

I have been tasked with enhancing an existing Weka system in Java by adding an export of the decision tree for consumption by offline components (ideally in JSON format, but XML could work too).

Let me warn you that I'm quite new to Weka :)

I *haven’t* found a way to get direct access to the J48’s Root Tree (appears to be private w/in the class)—are you aware of a way to get at it? If not, the closest I’ve found as a way to get at the data bit hackish:  use J48.toString() to dump the tree-as-string, and then convert that back into a Tree Structure and then convert that into a JSON string (YUK).

It seems that this use-case is not unusual, so I'm wondering if any of you all have already solved this problem . . . any direction/suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `graph()` method in `ClassifierTree` gives the [Graphviz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz) representation of the decision tree in a "dot" file.

If we take [this example](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/01/a-simple-machine-learning-example-in-java/), then the code

```
J48 g = (J48) models[0]; 
System.out.println(g.graph());
```

will return:

```
digraph J48Tree {
N0 [label="outlook" ]
N0->N1 [label="= sunny"]
N1 [label="humidity" ]
N1->N2 [label="<= 75"]
N2 [label="yes (2.0)" shape=box style=filled ]
N1->N3 [label="> 75"]
N3 [label="no (3.0)" shape=box style=filled ]
N0->N4 [label="= overcast"]
N4 [label="yes (4.0)" shape=box style=filled ]
N0->N5 [label="= rainy"]
N5 [label="yes (4.0/1.0)" shape=box style=filled ]
}
```

corresponding to this tree:

[image]

**To answer your question**,

> I haven’t found a way to get direct access to the J48’s Root Tree
>   (appears to be private w/in the class)—are you aware of a way to get
>   at it?

You could extend `J48` like below and declare you classifier as a `MyJ48` instead of `J48`:

```
class MyJ48 extends J48{

    public ClassifierTree getGraph(){
        return m_root;
    }

}
```

That enables to access the ClassifierTree using the `getGraph()` method. Based on that, you can mimic the `graph()` method of the `ClassifierTree` class (see [here](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall00/G22.3033-001/weka/weka-3-0-2/weka/classifiers/j48/ClassifierTree.java)) to generate your `json`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I guess that's the closest answer I can get to the one I wanted. Will look into your suggestion and see if I can somehow parse the graph output to a good JSON citizen. Will post the graph -> json parsing logic back once I am successful.

Comment: Not sure how "mimic the graph() method of the ClassifierTree" is possible after subclassing J48. In order to mimic it, I would need access to ClassifierTree's protected variables like m_localModel which I simply cant from MyJ48 class.